# creating xml from object with DOM parser in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am want to generate xml from java object and then storing that generated xml in a string I want to achieve this through DOM  parser that is creating a xml through DOM parser and then storing that in a string which later i will use for my own purpose later

please advise how to achieve this below is my pojo classes

```
public class InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage  {

    private String InvoiceReference;
    private String ABSReference;
    private String Currency;
    private double InvoiceAmount;
    private double PaidAmount;
    private double BalanceAmount;
    private Date ValueDate;
    private String Remarks;

     //setters & getters
    }
```

and below is my mail class in which there are references of my above pojo

```
public class Mail {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;

        private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage =    new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();

        public List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> getInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages() {
            return InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
        }

        public void addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages) {
            this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages;
        }
}
```

but I want the xml to be generated in the below fashion

```
<brokermail>

  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>        <!---  ***********1 st tag *********** ---->
   <InvoiceReference>SM/829767815</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>IRMAR157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>25555546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>1245.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:38:35.110 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
     </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>   <!---  *********** end 1 st tag *********** ---->

     <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>        <!--- ***********2 st tag **************---->
        <InvoiceReference>SM/15</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>I157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>255546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>125545.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:38:35.110 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abERRc</Remarks>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>     <!--- ***********end 2 st tag **************---->

</brokermail>
```

so i will be creating objects as of my pojo from my class as shown below...

```
InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceReference("SM/829709/0315");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setRBSReference("IRMAR157311");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setCurrency("GBP");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceAmount(2546);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setPaidAmount(1245);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setBalanceAmount(0);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setValueDate(new Date());
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setRemarks("abc");


    InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1 = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setInvoiceReference("SM/15");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setRBSReference("I157311");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setCurrency("EUR");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setInvoiceAmount(255546);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setPaidAmount(125545);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setBalanceAmount(0);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setValueDate(new Date());
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setRemarks("abERRc");

    List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest = new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1);

    Mail m = new Mail();
    m.addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest);
```

now finally want to call a method that will create a xml using DOM parser please advise how to achieve this

```
//method call to DOM parser

        String t = getXml(      List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest )
```

Folks please advise how to generate XML with the help of DOM parser

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do (based on your first paragraph).  A SAX Parser _parses_ things--it _parses_ XML files.  To _write_ an XML file you can use [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html) or [XMLStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) via the [XMLOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(...) methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.html#method_summary)

Comment: If you want to handle a Java object via a Sax Parser, then as you handle the object you need to generate the necessary events in the [`DefaultHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) that the SAX Parser parses with (e.g. [parse(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html#parse(java.io.File,%20org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler)).

Comment: @Jared i have updated my post could you please advise how to achieve that above xml with DOM parser please

Comment: Sorry, I know a little about SAX parsers (and XMLStreamWriter's)--but never really learned [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) (I think this is the same link I linked to above--but I would start [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)).

Comment: well please advise or paste the code to generate the above desired xml